# Page level content security policy

Tags: .net-core, razor-pages, content-security-policy

I have implemented a strong CSP in my startup class and everything is working well. However, I have an email editor in my application and this (razor) page needs to allow inline styles. Is there a way to override or modify the CSP at page level?

Comment: From the browser's point of view, the CSP is part of every response, so can be different on whatever pages you want. Perhaps you can give some more details of how you've currently implemented it, and why changing it on this page doesn't seem trivial?

Comment: Purely because the CSP is set in the startup class and thus applies to all requests. Also the headers don’t seem to be editable from the razor page itself… So I’m not sure how to amend or override the CSP on that one page.